# Getting a few images from a WebGL rendered canvas in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, web-applications, 3d, three.js

I am working on a web application where people can build a house a preview it in 3D. The 3D preview works well in firefox, chrome and IE11+ but it won't work with ie9. Is there a way to get a few images of the 3D scene they are supposed to see so that I can at least show them images of what their house looks like in 3D? I am using three.js.

Comment: IE9 wont support webgl, you can try canvas rendering, iam not sure about the texturing in canvas rendering, go through three.js examples on canvas rendering

Comment: It doesn't work in IE10 either actually.